# NoMethodError: undefined method `md5sum'

Tags: ruby, rspec, serverspec

When as the md5sum property added to the file resource type?  The version of Serverspec reports md5sum as not found.

```
describe file ('/etc/sysctl.conf' ) do
   it { should be_file }
   its(:md5sum) { should eq '07a47f3db13458ebc93b334973cc8720' }
   its(:sha256sum) { should eq 'd63896fa456d47dde634c592d46d1d39cb6183fdbc450a2581b6f12d977ee2d1' }
   it { should be_mode 644 }
   it { should be_owned_by 'root' }
   it { should be_grouped_into 'root' }
end

 Failure/Error: its(:md5sum) { should eq '07a47f3db13458ebc93b334973cc8720' }
 NoMethodError: undefined method `md5sum' for File "/etc/sysctl.conf":Serverspec::Type::File

apt-cache show ruby-serverspec
Package: ruby-serverspec
Version: 1.14.0-2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It was added on August 10, 2014](https://github.com/serverspec/serverspec/commit/68a2f8937d3c0cdeb7928128f74f8e7094b9e559). It was apparently released with version 2.0.0 on October 8, 2014.